# An error was encountered when setting batch_size to 1 in sequence_to_sequence_implementation.ipynb（when batch_size > 1,it 's ok）

Tags: python, tensorflow, encoder-decoder

reference:
https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning/blob/master/seq2seq/sequence_to_sequence_implementation.ipynb

setting:
encoding_embedding_size=decoding_embedding_size = 200

error info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "my_encoder_decoder.py", line 369, in 
    main(sys.argv[1])
    File "my_encoder_decoder.py", line 346, in main
    my_qa.train()
    File "my_encoder_decoder.py", line 298, in train
    model.build_graph()
    File "D:\vmware\share\test\chat\seq2seqmodel.py", line 197, in build_graph
    self._decoding_layer()
    File "D:\vmware\share\test\chat\seq2seqmodel.py", line 130, in _decoding_layer
    inference_decoder_output = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(inference_decoder,impute_finished=False,maximum_iterations=self.max_target_sequence_length)[0]
    File "d:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\seq2seq\python\ops\decoder.py", line 286, in dynamic_decode
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
    File "d:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2770, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
    File "d:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2599, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
    File "d:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2580, in _BuildLoop
    _EnforceShapeInvariant(m_var, n_var)
    File "d:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 575, in _EnforceShapeInvariant
    % (merge_var.name, m_shape, n_shape))
    ValueError: The shape for decode_1/decoder/while/Merge_5:0 is not an invariant for the loop. It enters the loop with shape (1, 200), but has shape (?, 200) after one iteration. Provide shape invariants using either the shape_invariants argument of tf.while_loop or set_shape() on the loop variables.

Does anyone know how to solve it?